# MySQL Updates are taking forever

Tags: java, mysql, performance

Hey, im trying to wirte about 600000 Tokens into my MySQL Database Table. The Engine I'm using is InnoDB. The update process is taking forever :(. So my best guess is that I'm totally missing something in my code and that what I'm doing is just plain stupid.

Perhaps someone has a spontaneous idea about what seems to eat my performance:

Here is my code:

```
public void writeTokens(Collection<Token> tokens){

    try{
        PreparedStatement updateToken = dbConnection.prepareStatement("UPDATE tokens SET `idTag`=?, `Value`=?, `Count`=?, `Frequency`=? WHERE `idToken`=?;");

        for (Token token : tokens) {

            updateToken.setInt(1, 0);
            updateToken.setString(2, token.getWord());
            updateToken.setInt(3, token.getCount());
            updateToken.setInt(4, token.getFrequency());
            updateToken.setInt(5, token.getNounID());

            updateToken.executeUpdate();
        }
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a Java-specific answer for you, but wrap the whole shebang in a transaction. If you don't, then MySQL (when writing against InnoDB) starts and commits a new transaction per update statement.

Just execute `START TRANSACTION` before you start your calls, and execute `COMMIT` after all your updates/inserts are done. I also think that MySQL defers index updates until the end of the transaction, as well, which should help improve performance considerably if you're updating indexed fields.

Comment: or this, should have the same effect, database-wise

Comment: These are all great answers ... it's sad that i can only accept one as my accepted answer because what really did the trick was a combination off all. Tanks again @All

Answer (score 4):

If you have an index on one or more of the fields in your table, each update enforces a rebuild of those indices, which may in fact take a while as you approach several hundreds of thousands of entries.

PreparedStatement comes with an addBatch() method - I haven't used it but if I get it correctly, you can transmit several batches of records to your prepared statement and then update in one go. This reduces the number of index rebuilds from 600.000 to 1 - you should feel the difference :)

Answer (score 3):

Each update statement requires a roundtrip to the database. This will give you a huge performance hit.

There are a couple of ways you insert this data into the database without performing hundreds of thousands of queries:

- Use a bulk insert ([LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)).
- Use a single insert statement that inserts multiple rows at once. You could for example insert 100 rows per insert statement.

Then you can use a single update statement to copy the data into the target table. This will reduce the number of server roundtrips, improving the performance.